# Expression issue with conditional logic in SSIS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, expression, ssis-2008

In an SSIS project, I am building expressions to create connection strings with dates from the prior weekday.  For example if today is Monday, I'm picking up files from Friday.  If today is Tuesday, I'm picking up files from Monday, and so on.

For the Monday example where I'm picking up files from 3 days ago, I've created the following successful expression:

```
    (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mm", GETDATE())==(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mm",DATEADD( "dd" , -3, GETDATE() ) ) ? "\\\\Sfa14\\tsibwdfa$\\EPSI Extracts\\Daily_Rec_Counts\\BWH_EPSI_Rec_Cnt_"+(DT_WSTR, 4) DATEPART( "yyyy",GETDATE() )+Right("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mm", DATEADD( "dd" , -0, GETDATE() ) ),2)+Right("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "dd", DATEADD( "dd" , -3, GETDATE() ) ) ,2): "\\\\Sfa14\\tsibwdfa$\\EPSI Extracts\\Daily_Rec_Counts\\BWH_EPSI_Rec_Cnt_"+(DT_WSTR, 4) DATEPART( "yyyy",GETDATE() )+Right("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mm", DATEADD( "mm" , -1, GETDATE() ) ),2)+Right("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "dd", DATEADD( "dd" , -3, GETDATE() ) ) ,2)+".txt"
```

It evaluates to \Sfa14\tsibwdfa$\EPSI Extracts\Daily_Rec_Counts\BWH_EPSI_Rec_Cnt_20160429.txt .

For the example where I'm only looking back one day prior, I used the same structure to create the following code, where the -3s have been changed to -1s.

```
    (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mm", GETDATE())==(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mm",DATEADD( "dd" , -1, GETDATE() ) ) ? "\\\\Sfa14\\tsibwdfa$\\EPSI Extracts\\Daily_Rec_Counts\\BWH_EPSI_Rec_Cnt_"+(DT_WSTR, 4) DATEPART( "yyyy",GETDATE() )+Right("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mm", DATEADD( "dd" , -0, GETDATE() ) ),2)+Right("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "dd", DATEADD( "dd" , -1, GETDATE() ) ) ,2): "\\\\Sfa14\\tsibwdfa$\\EPSI Extracts\\Daily_Rec_Counts\\BWH_EPSI_Rec_Cnt_"+(DT_WSTR, 4) DATEPART( "yyyy",GETDATE() )+Right("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mm", DATEADD( "mm" , -1, GETDATE() ) ),2)+Right("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "dd", DATEADD( "dd" , -1, GETDATE() ) ) ,2)+".txt"
```

This evaluates to \Sfa14\tsibwdfa$\EPSI Extracts\Daily_Rec_Counts\BWH_EPSI_Rec_Cnt_20160501 , without the .txt extension.  I'm unsure why I'm losing the .txt.

In trying to isolate, I have found my issue lies only in the boolean part of the conditional.  Changing the -3 to -1 is what triggers .txt being removed.

I have tried other numerical values -2 to -9 and they all create the correct string.  -0 and -1 are the only ones that drop the .txt.  I have verified that both sides of the boolean expression evaluate to 5, no NULLS.

Since the other numerical values appear to work correctly, I'm wondering if there's a syntax restriction for -0 or -1 based on the way I've set up the boolean.

This is my first post; please let me know if I need to include additional documentation.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue.  I had omitted the +".txt" for the true piece of the expression.